# Django Rest Framework call filter method from client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a user filter class:

```
class UserFilterSet(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'email': ['exact', 'contains'],
            'first_name': ['iexact', 'icontains', 'in'],
            'last_name': ['iexact', 'icontains', 'in']
        }

    def dashboard_lookup(self, queryset, name, value):
        search_args = []
        for term in value.split():
            for query in ('first_name__icontains', 'last_name__icontains', 'email__icontains'):
                search_args.append(Q(**{query: term}))

        return queryset.filter(reduce(operator.or_, search_args))
```

My question is - how do I actually use this from my client? Right now I'm making requests to either `first_name` or `last_name` or `email`, but I need to filter by any of the three in the same request. Hence the `method` approach above. Is there a way to add this method to the querystring? Maybe something like `https://mypage.com/api/user/?method=dashboard_lookup&value=string`?

Comment: You just need at add a field to your `FilterSet` that uses `dashboard_lookup` as `method` as shown [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method)

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks, worked!